# Extract from NSDictionary object

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, json-framework

I used json-framework to pull a JSON string from and URL and convert the JSON string to `NSDictionary` object with these two lines of code

```
SBJsonParser* parser = [SBJsonParser new];
NSDictionary* myDict = [parser objectWithString:resp];
```

My `NSDicitonary` has:

```
(
        {
        condition = no;
        date = "2013-06-21";
        "location_id" = 9;
        name = Chabahil;
        reason = "";
        time = "03:04:22";
    },
        {
        condition = pressure;
        date = "2013-06-21";
        "location_id" = 7;
        name = Maitighar;
        reason = "Peak Hour";
        time = "03:04:13";
    }
)
```

Now I need to access each element for example I want to get value of "name" of the second element. I couldnot figure out how to do it.
Thanks!

Comment: If I understand your question right you can access to every elements like this NSString* name = myDict[@"name"]; If you want to get names of all elements you can send message to dictionary like this:  NSArray* names = [myDict allKeys];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON string contains not a *dictionary*, but an *array* (of two dictionaries).
So you would do

```
SBJsonParser* parser = [SBJsonParser new];
NSArray* jsonArray = [parser objectWithString:resp];
```

and access the values for example like

```
NSString *secondName = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

or, using the modern subscripting syntax:

```
NSString *secondName = jsonArray[1][@"name"];
```

(Note that there already is a `NSJSONSerialization` class in Foundation, so unless you
have a specific reason to use `SBJsonParser`, you could use that as well.)